# Split single column values and assign to multiple column dynamically

Tags: plsql

I have two table like below with the values concatenated with pipeline symbol.

Table 1: In this table which has column name to split in Column B as below

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Customer Details | Name|Age|Sex|Email|Mobile |
| Customer Address | Address1|Address2|City|State|Country |

Table 2: In this table which has column values to split and assign to the column which was split in table 1 as below mentioned in Results

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Customer Details | XXX|46|Male|xyz@yy.com|9xxxxxxxxxx |
| Customer Address | Xyz Avenue|YYY|XXXXXX|XXXXX|XXXXXX |

Need Results as below. Here column A would be dynamic so based on that I need to split the columns and assign respective values.

If column A = 'Customer Details' then results would display as below

| Name | Age | Sex | Email | Mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 46 | Male | xyz@yy.com | 9xxxxxxxxxx |

If column A = 'Customer Address' then results would display as below

| Address1 | Address2 | City | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Xyz Avenue | YYY | XXXXXX | XXXXX | XXXXXX |

Note: The columns might be get added in future so I'm looking to split them dynamically. So can someone help me on this to get the desired result (as mentioned above)?

I have tried `regex_substr` to split and this works only for static but I need this to work dynamically.

Comment: To me, it looks as if it would be better if you discarded such an approach and normalize data model.

Comment: Why is it not possible

Comment: I didn't say that it is not possible. It is, but you have to write some code and maintain it every time you add a new column. Too much job for no benefits - again, from my point of view.

Comment: i dont know where you see a problem here, well written regex should solve the case.
Could you post your queries that you tried to use but you failed ?